# Some versus certain

Tags: expressions

I understand that "some + noun" should be used for unspecific situations, and "certain + noun" for specific ones. However, I don't know if this rule applies to certain expressions such as the below ones. Are some and certain interchangeable when using these expressions, or does the unspecific vs. specific rule still apply?

> in some cases / in certain cases

> to some degree / to a certain degree

> at some point in time / at a certain point in time

Answer (score 1):

As is the case with much of English usage, the correctness of these examples is highly dependent upon the context in which they are used.

- We don't know why yet, but in some cases the medicine had no effect.
- The medicine was generally effective, but in certain cases it didn't help.

What the "some cases" have in common is unknown, we only know that they exist.
But we *do* know what the "certain cases" have in common (e.g. people that had previous exposure to the disease), and we can use this knowledge to predict future behaviour.

- The medicine helped to some degree, but the results had great variability from one test to another.
- The medicine helped to a certain degree, but not enough that we should continue with this line of research.

The "some degree" means that there was a noticeable effect, but it's impossible to say how much.
The "certain degree" means that it helped a specific small percentage of the subjects. The actual number is known, but the important idea is that it is very small.

- At some point in time you will realize that I was right.
- We sat fishing all day. At a certain point in time we realized that we would never catch anything but didn't really care.

The "some point" is certain to happen, but we don't know when.
The "certain point" is known (e.g. at 11:15), but exactly when is irrelevant to the idea being expressed.

A general guideline would be:

- use "some" to refer to something that is true but can't be easily or precisely characterized.
- use "certain" to refer to something that can be characterized but doesn't need to be.
- use the actual characteristic when it is known and is important to the idea being expressed.

Comment: Yes… "certain" is more and "some" is less specific, but there's no rule for how much less or more.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder then why do reputable dictionaries define things such as "to some extent" with the definition "to a certain extent", or introduce them as synonyms, when their meanings are different.

Comment: @baitas, because unlike other natural languages such as French, English doesn't have a central authority that tries to keep everything to a standard, and unlike artificial languages such as Python, English still works fairly well even when the rules aren't followed. Most dictionaries define how English words *are* used, not how they *must be* used. In informal use, in most cases, "certain" and "some" are interchangeable without changing the understanding of what is being said. It's in formal use, such as legal or scientific documents, where meanings must be precise.

Answer (score 0):

The rule you mention in your first sentence isn't true. It's a *smart rule to follow* when you're first learning English though, because it's harder to make mistakes that way, but it's not true in English in general.

The truth is that in some contexts, the word "some" carries the meaning "specific". In other contexts, it means "random" or "arbitrary", which are the opposite of "specific". In others still, it could mean either, and it's not clear.

If it's clear from the context that "some" means "*specific*", then "some" and "certain" are interchangeable:

> I really get along well with almost everyone, but there's **some** types of people who really get on my nerves.

If it's clear from the context that "some" means "*arbitrary*", then it's not interchangeable with "certain":

> I didn't see who they were. It was just **some** guys.

When it's *unclear*, we usually understand it to mean "arbitrary":

> **Some** people irritate me.

Here, it's not clear whether the speaker means, "Specific people irritate me" or "Some arbitrary people irritate me". Without context, we'll probably understand the second meaning.

All three of your examples with "some" are *unclear*. In a fuller context, those phrases could mean something specific or something arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you! What is *certain* at least, is that "certain" always implies specificity.